# leaflet map not removing makers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using a leaflet map in order to display some markers.
I would like to set up a button that on click will remove all the markers on the map and create new one, however i am having trouble removing the markers

I am using some directions I have seen on documentation and forums but nothing seems to work..
when the user click on the button it trigger the method onclick={QualifiedhandleClick}

here is the way I init my map

```
  initialized = false

  renderedCallback(){
      if(this.initialized) return;
      this.initialized = true;
      console.log('rendered')
      const mapContainer = this.template.querySelector(".map-container");
      Object.assign(mapContainer.style, {
        position: "relative",
        height: "600px"
      });
      
  
      const mapEl = this.template.querySelector(".map");
      


      Object.assign(mapEl.style, {
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        top: 0
      })

      


      

  }


 async start() {

    await loadScript(this, Leaflet + '/Leaflet/leaflet.js')
    await loadScript(this, Leaflet + '/Leaflet/leaflet.draw.js')
    await loadStyle(this, Leaflet + '/Leaflet/leaflet.css')
    await loadStyle(this, Leaflet + '/Leaflet/leaflet.draw.css')
    await loadStyle(this, Leaflet + '/Leaflet/MarkerCluster.css')
    await loadScript(this, Leaflet + '/Leaflet/leaflet.markercluster.js')
    await loadStyle(this, Leaflet + '/Leaflet/MarkerCluster.Default.css')

    Promise.all([
      getPropertyList({ MarkerId: this.recordId })
      
  ]).then((res) => {
    var CleanedList = this.cleanCoordinate(res[0])
    this.allData = CleanedList;
    if(CleanedList.length > 0){
        this.toDisplay = true;
    } else{
        this.toDisplay = false;
    }
    var medianCoordinated = this.getMedianCoordinates(CleanedList);
    this.InitiatedmedianCoordinated = medianCoordinated
    this.init(CleanedList, medianCoordinated[0]['MedianLatitude'], medianCoordinated[0]['MedianLongitude']);

    const ready = new CustomEvent("ready");        
    this.dispatchEvent(ready);
      // Leaflet should be ready, create a new draw method
      // this.draw();
  })
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.start();
}

  init(CleanedList, Lat, Long) {
    console.log('gogo');

   
    this.markersGroup = CleanedList;
    console.log('gogo2');
    const mapEl = this.template.querySelector(".map");
    console.log('gogo3', mapEl);
    console.log(this.map)
    this.map = L.map(mapEl).setView([Lat, Long], 13);
    console.log('gogo4');
 

    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.map);
    console.log('gogo4');

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    if (this.filters.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i <= this.filters.length; i++) {
        if (this.filters[i] && this.filters[i].field && this.filters[i].value) {
 
          const key = this.filters[i].field;
          if (this.filters[i].operator === 'Equals') {
            CleanedList = CleanedList.filter(d => d[this.filters[i].field] == this.filters[i].value)
          } else if (this.filters[i].operator === 'Not Equals') {
            CleanedList = CleanedList.filter(d => d[this.filters[i].field] !== this.filters[i].value)
          } else if (this.filters[i].operator === 'Less Than') {
            CleanedList = CleanedList.filter(d => d[this.filters[i].field] < this.filters[i].value)
          } else if (this.filters[i].operator === 'Greater Than') {
            CleanedList = CleanedList.filter(d => d[this.filters[i].field] > this.filters[i].value)
          } else if (this.filters[i].operator === 'Less Or Equal') {
            CleanedList = CleanedList.filter(d => d[this.filters[i].field] <= this.filters[i].value)
          } else if (this.filters[i].operator === 'Greater Or Equal') {
            CleanedList = CleanedList.filter(d => d[this.filters[i].field] >= this.filters[i].value)
          } else if (this.filters[i].operator === 'Contains') {

            CleanedList = CleanedList.filter(d => d[this.filters[i].field].includes(this.filters[i].value))

          } else if (this.filters[i].operator === 'Does Not Contains') {
            CleanedList = CleanedList.filter(d => !d[this.filters[i].field].includes(this.filters[i].value))
          }
        } 
      }
    }
    this.PropCount = CleanedList.length;
    this.currentDisplayedPropertiesOnMap = CleanedList

    CleanedList.forEach((r) => {
        markers.addLayer(L.marker([r.Latitude, r.Longitude])
        .bindPopup(r.name)
        .on("click", (e) => {
          this.qwerty = {pin: r, data: CleanedList};
        }));
    });
  

    var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();

    this.map.addLayer(editableLayers);

    this.map.addLayer(markers);

    const drawControlSettings = {
      
      draw : {
          position : 'topleft',
          polyline : false,
          rectangle : false,
          circle : false,
          marker: false,
          circlemarker: false,
      },
      edit: {
        featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
        remove: true
      }
    
  };

// Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(drawControlSettings);
this.map.addControl(drawControl);


this.map.on('draw:created', (e) => {
  console.log('Map On')
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

  editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
  console.log('Map On2')
  const mapData = [];
  const layers= Object.values(editableLayers._layers);
  layers.forEach(layer => {
    mapData.push(CleanedList.filter(r => this.isMarkerInsidePolygon(r, layer)));
  })
  
  markers.clearLayers()
  this.PropCount = mapData[0].length;
  mapData[0].forEach((r) => {
    markers.addLayer(L.marker([r.Latitude, r.Longitude])
    .bindPopup(r.name)
    .on("click", (e) => {
      this.qwerty = {pin: r, data: CleanedList};
    }));
});

  //////////////////////////
  this.qwerty = {pin: undefined, data: CleanedList, mapData: mapData.flat(2)};
});



this.map.on('draw:edited', (e) => {
  console.log('Map Created')
  const mapData = [];
  const layers= Object.values(editableLayers._layers);
  layers.forEach(layer => {
    mapData.push(CleanedList.filter(r => this.isMarkerInsidePolygon(r, layer)));
  })

  const array = mapData.flat(2).length > 0 ? mapData.flat(2) : undefined;

  this.qwerty = {pin: undefined, data: CleanedList, mapData: array};
});

this.map.on('draw:deleted', (e) => {
  console.log('deleted')
  const mapData = [];
  const layers= Object.values(editableLayers._layers);
  layers.forEach(layer => {
    mapData.push(CleanedList.filter(r => this.isMarkerInsidePolygon(r, layer)));
  })
  markers.clearLayers()
  CleanedList.forEach((r) => {
    markers.addLayer(L.marker([r.Latitude, r.Longitude])
    .bindPopup(r.name)
    .on("click", (e) => {
      this.qwerty = {pin: r, data: CleanedList};
    }));
    this.PropCount = CleanedList.length;
});
  
  

  const array = mapData.flat(2).length > 0 ? mapData.flat(2) : undefined;
  

  this.qwerty = {pin: undefined, data: CleanedList, mapData: array};
});

const preparedData = CleanedList.map(r => {
  return {
    ...r, label: r.Name, value: r.id
  }
});


this.qwerty = {pin: undefined, data: preparedData};


    
}

     QualifiedhandleClick(event){
        console.log('test');
        this.map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            console.log(layer)
            this.map.removeLayer(layer); 
        });
        console.log('deleted')
           
      });
```

any idea ?

Comment: have you tried wrapping your markers inside of a FeatureGroup and then remove the featuregroup with
this.map.removeLayer(featureGroup);

Comment: actualy I am using a FeatureGroup I posted how do I init my map

Comment: we still don't see where markers is instanciated. if it's a featureGroup too, try to call 
this.map.removeLayer(markers)

Comment: I pushed all my initiation .. 
the thins is that my button is outside my init function so I am having trouble getting to the markers

Comment: sorry but this is pretty messy code. are you sure it really is a leaflet problem ? do your console.log(layer) gets fired and output something ? are you inside of a JS class ? If so, what is the entrypoint ? A working fiddle or stackblitz would help

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the FeatureGroups:

```
 QualifiedhandleClick(event){
    console.log('test');
    teditableLayers.clearLayers();
    markers.clearLayers();
    console.log('deleted') 
  });
```

Comment: I do not manage to access editableLayers since my function is outside of the init map .. so it is undefined

Comment: I guess I should maybe use this.map but but do not manage to remove markers

Comment: Create the `editableLayers` outside of the function and add a value in the init to it. `var editableLayers; .... init(){editableLayers = L.featureGroup();`